# Problem with 3 monitor configuration (2 monitors and a TV)

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, radeon

Hello I've been seraching a lot in the web about my problem but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I have an ATI RADEON HD 6870, I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity and AMD Catalyst 11.12,and I have 2 monitors Samsung S20A300BS connected by the DVI port and a LG TV 32LD450 connected by the HDMI port.

The thing is that I want to use the 2 monitors for working and use the TV to watch movies and TV shows, I have the 2 monitors working perfectly together but I can't use the 3 screens at the same time, I've tried every possible configuration with AMD CCC but it doesn't let me use the TV (I open it using **sudo amdcccle** on the terminal so it will give me the option of restart the PC and save changes but after rebooting nothing happens).

**First** I tried to use the 3 screens with the "Multi-display desktop" option.

**Second** I tried to use the 2 monitors with the "Multi-display desktop" option and I use the "Single display desktop" on the TV but what I got was a **blank screen** on the TV.

**Third** I used the 2 monitors with the "Multi-display desktop" option and the "Cloned display from display(s) 1" on the TV because I don't necessary have to use the monitors at the same time as the TV so that was an option, but it still didn't give anything on the TV after rebooting.

All the times after rebooting I went to "Displays" option in Ubuntu and tried to configure the monitors and I got the same errors:

**The selected configuration for displays could not be applied**
**could not set the configuration for CRTC 148**

From all the configurations that I tried the only thing that varies is that give me the CRTC 417, CRTC 148, or the CRTC 149 errors.

One thing that I tried and worked 1 time in the **Displays** option was to turn OFF the 2 monitors and turn ON just the TV and only that time gave me signal on the TV (but I can't do it anymore I don't know why)

So anyone have any idea what can I do to configure my computer or where can I look for the problem??? Because this is driven me crazy!!!!! I was going to upload screenshots but I need 10 reputation jeje

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use both DVI connectors and HDMI -- it's not just an Ubuntu/Linux thing, it's a physical limitation of the card.  You can only use two of them (any combination) at any given time.

To connect a third display, you'll need to connect it via displayport (you can get displayport -> dvi adapters, etc).